# Json variable assignment python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to assignment variables to the following json from a rest API:

.json

https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product

.py

```
response = requests.get("https://{0}{1}".format(session.get("shop"), endpoint), headers=headers)
    print(response)

    #If connection has been successfull ...
    if response.status_code == 200:
        products = json.loads(response.text)

    for product in products:
        ###PRINT VARIABLES####
        print(product['id']
        print(product['title'])
        print(product['title']['variants']['product_id'])
```

The above however returns the following error.

KeyError: 'title'

I have further tried;

```
        print(products['product']['title']
        print(product(product).title
```

and various others with no success.

Any help parsing this json would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: the JSON source file has a syntax error:  add `",` after `8GB`

Comment: Can you update the question to show the complete error traceback of the error "KeyError: 'title'". Also, can you specify whats contained in ```response.text``` before doing ```json.loads```

Comment: JSON is malformed, it cannot start from double quote `"`

Comment: this is the json reponse. https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with loading the json data into `products` variable. After loading, you are trying to retrieve values from `products` in an incorrect manner which leads to Key Error. Your `products` is basically a dictionary of list of dictionary

Here is the correct way to retrieve necessary values from products:

```
print(products['products'][0]['id'])
#632910392
print(products['products'][0]['title'])
#IPod Nano - 8GB
print(products['products'][0]['variants'][0]['product_id'])
#632910392
```

Try analysing the deep structure of your `products` variable so that you can learn to retrieve any value in it by yourself. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Consider accessing the array by using `products["products"]` for instance:

```
import json
result = json.loads('{"products": [ {"id": "1234", "title": "foo"} ]}')
for it in result["products"]:
    print("id: " + it["id"] + " title: " + it["title"])
```